# How to make text change to different text that is clickable on hover?

Tags: html, css

I need help on some HTML/CSS styling. I have a cart widget on my website that shows the items in the users cart, and it displays the item quantity, the name, the price, and a button to remove the item. [This is what it looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RtpG.png) Now, what I want is for it to only display the quantity, the item name, and the price on the far right, and I want the word "remove" to appear whenever the user hovers over the item, replacing the price on the far right. So, I want there to normally be just the quantity, the name of the item, and the price. When the user hovers over the cart item, I want the price to be replaced with the word "remove". Here's the html of the widget:

```
<div id="modal" style="width: auto; height: auto; top: 178px; left: 542.5px; display: block;"><div id="content">
    <!--dynamic-cached-content-->

    <li class="cart_item empty" style="display: none;"><span class="edd_empty_cart">Your cart is empty.</span></li>
<li class="edd-cart-item">
<span class="edd-cart-item-quantity">&nbsp;1&nbsp;</span><span class="edd-cart-item-separator">&nbsp;-&nbsp;</span><span class="edd-cart-item-title">The Grant</span>
<span class="edd-cart-item-price">&nbsp;$2.00&nbsp;</span><span class="edd-cart-item-separator">-</span>
<a href="http://baylornorrisphotography.com/checkout/?cart_item=0&amp;edd_action=remove&amp;nocache=true" data-cart-item="0" data-download-id="3573" data-action="edd_remove_from_cart" class="edd-remove-from-cart">remove</a>
</li>
<li class="cart_item edd-cart-meta edd_total" style="">Total: <span class="cart-total">$2.00</span></li>
<li class="cart_item edd_checkout" style=""><a href="http://baylornorrisphotography.com/checkout/">Checkout</a></li>
    <!--/dynamic-cached-content-->
</div><a id="modal-close" href="#"><i class="fa fa-times-circle-o"></i></a>
</div>
```

And here's the CSS that I have:

```
body,
button,
input,
textarea {
    color: #55b6fb;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    line-height: 1.75;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

And for the remove button:

```
a.edd-remove-from-cart {
    color: #666;
}

a.edd-remove-from-cart:hover {
    color: #e56363;
}
```

I'm sorry if this isn't enough information. If you need more CSS or HTML, tell me what you need and I can copy and paste it. Thank you all so much!

Answer (score 0):

For this type of question, it's best to provide a live example.

I suspect you can do this pretty easily with CSS :hover pseudo class.

You may find help on easy digital downloads forum as well.

Looks like you are missing parent UL tag :/

This should do the trick.

```
#modal #content li.edd-cart-item {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    position: relative;
}

a.edd-remove-from-cart {
    color: #666;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}

#modal #content li.edd-cart-item:hover a {
    display: inherit;
}
```

Comment: If you want a live example, you can visit the website! I've been fooling around with the developer tools in Chrome to live edit the webpage. [Here's the link](http://baylornorrisphotography.com). Let me know if this helps at all!